# If $V$ is a vector space then $(V,+)$ is a characteristically simple abelian group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, abelian-groups

(From Rotman, *"Introduction to the Theory of Groups"*)
I am not really sure where to start with this one.

I know that characteristically simple groups can be expressed as internal direct products of pairwise isomorphic, finite simple groups. And that we can find a basis for any subspace, $U$ of $V$ that can be extended to a subspace $W$ for the whole space so that $V=U\oplus W$.

But I'm not sure how to translate between the language of groups and the language of vector spaces in this proof.

Surely we can't just use $(U,+)$ and $(W,+)$ as direct factors, as they may not be isomorphic!

Comment: Note that linear transformations are abelian group morphisms. If $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ are nonzero elements of $V$, then there exists a linear transformation $V\to V$ that (i) maps $\mathbf{v}$ to $\mathbf{w}$; and (ii) is bijective (hence an abelian group automorphism of $V$). In particular, no proper nontrivial subgroup of $V$ can be characteristic in $V$.

Comment: (Your argument runs into problems when $V$ is one-dimensional, because whereas every subspace is a subgroup, not every subgroup is a subspace. For instance, $\mathbb{R}$ is a one-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ so it cannot be decomposed as a direct sum of nontrivial subsapces, but it has lots of proper nontrivial subgroups, such as $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$)

Comment: As an additive group, $V$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of ${\mathbb Q}$ or of copies of cyclic groups of the same prime order, depending on the characteristic of the field. Which exercise is this exactly, and in which edition of Rotman?

Comment: I don't know about Rotman but Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"* has this as **Exercise 3.1.5.**